# How  to get a post's author ID in phpBB?

Tags: php, forum, phpbb

How to get the author ID from inside a theme, in the viewtopic.php file?

The author-theme id is in viewforum (or topic - it doesn't matter very much).

I want to know how to get the ID and use it in the viewtopic.php file.

Comment: There is no `viewpost.php` file in my phpbb2 and phpbb3 installations. What file do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the topic author ID using the $topic_data['topic_poster'] which is fetched on line 272 in viewtopic.php file. If you are however looking for the ID of the author of each individual post / response to the topic, you can fetch that from $poster_id variable inside viewtopic.php file.